# How can i achieve below design in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

can you some one help me to achieve below design i'm not be able to achieve the same design

[image]

bellow is my code

```
<View style={{ position: 'absolute',  padding:8, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, marginLeft: 30, width: '25%', top: 120, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
    <Text>From</Text>
</View>

<View style={{padding:10, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, width: '95%', alignSelf: 'center', borderRadius: 7, marginTop: 25 }}>
   <Text>MAPLIN STORE</Text>
   <Text>12 Kwame Nkrumah Bvd</Text>
   <Text>Pune, INDIA</Text>
</View>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <View style={{padding:10, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, width: '95%', alignSelf: 'center', borderRadius: 7, marginTop: 25 }}>
       <View style={{ padding: 8, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, marginLeft: 20, width: '25%', backgroundColor: 'white',bottom: 33}}>
           <Text>From</Text>
       </View>
   <Text>MAPLIN STORE</Text>
   <Text>12 Kwame Nkrumah Bvd</Text>
   <Text>Pune, INDIA</Text>
 </View>
```

try this code it's simple and nit code no need to extra main view and position
hope it would be help

Answer (score 2):

Something like this works for you?

```
<View>
   <View style={{padding:10, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, width: '95%', alignSelf: 'center', borderRadius: 7, marginTop: 25 }}>
       <View style={{ position: 'relative',  padding:8, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, marginLeft: 20, width: '25%',                 backgroundColor: 'white',bottom: 33}}>
           <Text>From</Text>
       </View>
   <Text>MAPLIN STORE</Text>
   <Text>12 Kwame Nkrumah Bvd</Text>
   <Text>Pune, INDIA</Text>
   </View>
 </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link https://snack.expo.io/B1inoHHVV you already got your answer may hope it will also help you

```
<View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center'}}>
 <View style={{padding:10,margin:5,borderColor:'black',borderWidth:2}}>
  <View style= 
   {{borderColor:'black',
    borderWidth:1,width:120,
    bottom:30,
    backgroundColor:'white'}}>
    <Button title="From"/>
     </View>
  <View style={{margin:10}}> 
   <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>MAPLIN STORE</Text>
   <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>12 Kwame Nkrumah Bvd</Text>
   <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>PUNE INDIA</Text>
  </View>
  </View>
 </View>
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer :)